# How to adjust groups of numbers to match ratios

Tags: algorithm

Imagine you have a list of objects which have 3 properties, R and U which can be both be either true or false, and a numeric value

What I'd like to do is adjust the numeric values so 20% of the total is made up of R=true objects, and 85% of the total is made up of U=true objects.
I'm looking to do this by multiplying all R=true values by a value (x) and all R=false values by another value (y)

e.g
.
If a is the total of R=false values, and b is the total of R=true values

to get the adjustment (x) you can say
(b*x) / ((b*x) + a) = 0.2
so
x =((0.2*a)/((0 - 0.2) +1)) / b

If I multiply all the R=true values by x, the total where R=true is 20% of the total

I can do the same this for U, if c is the total of U=false and d is the total of U=true
y=((0.2*c)/((0 - 0.2) + 1)) / d

Multiplying all the U=true values by y, the total where U=true is 85% of the total

So far so good, but... if I do them both, one adjustment throws the other one out.

Is there a way to get values for x and y to fulfill both ratios? It seems like there should be but my brain (or lack of maths knowledge) is letting me down.

I've tried asking this on math.stackexchange.com as it feels quite mathsy, but I'm struggling to explain what I mean using maths notation.
Also as a programmer I find their lack of brackets disturbing

If theres a nice way to do this, I might expand it by adding more properties and ratios...

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two approaches.  The first is a lot of messy algebra that won't generalize.  The second is some clever calculus that does.  (Don't worry, you won't need to know calculus to use the second approach.  But the more calculus you know, the more interesting it will be.)

For the first let's define:

```
a = sum(values where     U and     R)
b = sum(values where     U and not R)
c = sum(values where not U and     R)
d = sum(values where not U and not R)
```

Now you want:

```
x*y*a + x*b + y*c + d = 0.2*(x*y*a + x*b)
x*y*a + x*b + y*c + d = 0.85*(x*y*a + y*c)
```

Therefore:

```
0.2*(x*y*a + x*b) = 0.85*(x*y*a + y*c)
0.2*x*b = 0.65*x*y*a + 0.85*y*c
0.2*x*b / (0.65*x*a + 0.85*y*c) = y
```

If you substitute that back into as `y` one of the first two equations, then multiply by `(0.65*x*a + 0.85*y*c)`, you'll get a quadratic equation.  You can find two roots for `x`.  Substitute them back in and you'll get corresponding values for `y`.  And that will be your answer.

I won't actually do it because I guarantee that I'll get it wrong.  But here is the calculus approach.  I will use Python.

First we need some data.  This is just an array of dictionaries.

```
objects = [
    {"U": True, "V": True, "value": 1},
    {"U": True, "V": False, "value": 2},
    {"U": False, "V": True, "value": 3},
    {"U": False, "V": False, "value": 4},
    {"U": True, "V": False, "value": 5},
    {"U": False, "V": True, "value": 6},
    {"U": True, "V": True, "value": 7},
    {"U": False, "V": False, "value": 8},
    {"U": True, "V": True, "value": 9},
    {"U": False, "V": True, "value": 10},
]
```

Now we'll be using higher order functions a lot.  A higher order function is just a function that returns other functions.  So here is an example to extract fields out of our objects.

```
def field_fn (field):
    def inner (element):
        return element[field]
    return inner
```

So we take the name of a field, and we get a function that extracts that field from our objects.

Now let's add a function that summarizes our objects.

```
def grouped (elements, value_fn, test_fns):
    grouping = {}
    for e in elements:
        value = value_fn(e)
        category = []
        for test_fn in test_fns:
            category.append(test_fn(e))
        key = tuple(category)
        if key in grouping:
            grouping[key] += value
        else:
            grouping[key] = value
    return grouping
```

What we will do is something like `grouping(objects, field_fn("value"), [field_fn("U"), field_fn("V")])` and we'll get a dictionary that, but combination of truth values, gives us the total value.  In other words it computes `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` above.  Or more, if we have more.

Next we want to know how well we're doing in meeting our equations.  Where above we started with:

```
x*y*a + x*b + y*c + d = 0.2*(x*y*a + x*b)
x*y*a + x*b + y*c + d = 0.85*(x*y*a + y*c)
```

we are instead going to look at:

```
(x*y*a + x*b + y*c + d - 0.2*(x*y*a + x*b))**2 +
(x*y*a + x*b + y*c + d - 0.85*(x*y*a + y*c))**2
```

If that is close to 0, then both equations are close to matching.  If it is far from 0, then we aren't close to the solution we want.  So we want a function `f` such that `f([x, y])` gives that result.  Here is the code for that.

```
def ratio_fit_fn (grouping, ratios):
    def inner (factors):
        total = 0
        per_test = [0 for _ in ratios]
        for key, value in grouping.items():
            for i in range(len(ratios)):
                if key[i]:
                    value *= factors[i]
            total += value
            for i in range(len(ratios)):
                if key[i]:
                    per_test[i] += value
        fit = 0
        for i in range(len(ratios)):
            fit += (total * ratios[i] - per_test[i])**2
        return fit
    return inner
```

OK, so we have the ability to take the objects, summarize them, and figure out whether we seem to be close to a solution.  Now we need some calculus!

First, we need a function that calculates derivatives.  That is, it takes an input function of one variable, and returns an approximation of the derivative function.  Then pass a value into the derivative, and we'll get a slope.  We'll do it approximately.

```
def derivative (fn, delta=0.001):
    def inner (x):
        return (fn(x + delta/2) - fn(x - delta/2)) / delta
    return inner
```

But we don't have a function of one variable.  We have a function of many variables.  We need to be able to calculate the gradient of that function at a point.  The gradient is basically, "In each direction, how fast is it rising?"  If it is rising at a rate of `1` in the `x` direction, and `5` in the `y` direction, the gradient is `[1, 5]`.

If you're lost, just trust me that this code does that.

```
def gradient (fn, point):
    grad = []

    for i in range(len(point)):
        # This will be the function of just varying this dimension.
        def fn_i (x):
            point2 = [_ for _ in point]
            point2[i] += x
            return fn(point2)
        grad.append(derivative(fn_i)(0))

    return grad
```

Now why do we want this?  Because we want to be able to minimize our function.  (Hopefully the minimum is 0.)  To minimize we want to start somewhere, calculate the gradient.  Then we want to normalize the gradient - find just a vector of length 1 pointing in the same direction.  Then take a step DOWN the slope.  If we take a small enough step, we'll come closer.  So we start taking big steps, and whenever they are too big we take smaller.  We continue until we've taken a tiny step.

This sounds complicated, but here is the code with various sanity checks for "we got stuck".

```
def minimize (fn, start_point, step_size=1, finish_size = 0.0000001, max_iter=1000000):
    point = start_point
    n = 0
    while finish_size < step_size and n < max_iter:
        n += 1
        g = gradient(fn, point)
        g2 = sum((x*x for x in g))**0.5
        if 0 == g2:
            return point
        else:
            # The direction in which we go.
            # A vector of length 1 pointing AWAY from the gradient.
            vec = [-x/g2 for x in g]
            start = fn(point)
            point2 = [step_size * vec[i] + point[i] for i in range(len(point))]
            end = fn(point2)
            while start < end:
                step_size /= 2
                point2 = [step_size * vec[i] + point[i] for i in range(len(point))]
                end = fn(point2)
            point = point2
    return point
```

And then we put all of it together.

```
def optimize(objects, value_fn, field_fns_and_ratios):
    field_fns = [fr[0] for fr in field_fns_and_ratios]
    ratios = [fr[1] for fr in field_fns_and_ratios]
    grouping = grouped(objects, value_fn, field_fns)
    fit_fn = ratio_fit_fn(grouping, ratios)
    return minimize(fit_fn, [1 for _ in ratios])

print(optimize(objects, field_fn("value"), [(field_fn("U"), 0.2), (field_fn("V"), 0.85)]))
```

And here is all of the code in one place for your cut and paste pleasure.

```
def field_fn (field):
    def inner (element):
        return element[field]
    return inner

def grouped (elements, value_fn, test_fns):
    grouping = {}
    for e in elements:
        value = value_fn(e)
        category = []
        for test_fn in test_fns:
            category.append(test_fn(e))
        key = tuple(category)
        if key in grouping:
            grouping[key] += value
        else:
            grouping[key] = value
    return grouping

def ratio_fit_fn (grouping, ratios):
    def inner (factors):
        total = 0
        per_test = [0 for _ in ratios]
        for key, value in grouping.items():
            for i in range(len(ratios)):
                if key[i]:
                    value *= factors[i]
            total += value
            for i in range(len(ratios)):
                if key[i]:
                    per_test[i] += value
        fit = 0
        for i in range(len(ratios)):
            fit += (total * ratios[i] - per_test[i])**2
        return fit
    return inner

def derivative (fn, delta=0.001):
    def inner (x):
        return (fn(x + delta/2) - fn(x - delta/2)) / delta
    return inner

def gradient (fn, point):
    grad = []

    for i in range(len(point)):
        # This will be the function of just varying this dimension.
        def fn_i (x):
            point2 = [_ for _ in point]
            point2[i] += x
            return fn(point2)
        grad.append(derivative(fn_i)(0))

    return grad

def minimize (fn, start_point, step_size=1, finish_size = 0.0000001, max_iter=1000000):
    point = start_point
    n = 0
    while finish_size < step_size and n < max_iter:
        n += 1
        g = gradient(fn, point)
        g2 = sum((x*x for x in g))**0.5
        if 0 == g2:
            return point
        else:
            # The direction in which we go.
            # A vector of length 1 pointing AWAY from the gradient.
            vec = [-x/g2 for x in g]
            start = fn(point)
            point2 = [step_size * vec[i] + point[i] for i in range(len(point))]
            end = fn(point2)
            while start < end:
                step_size /= 2
                point2 = [step_size * vec[i] + point[i] for i in range(len(point))]
                end = fn(point2)
            point = point2
    return point

def optimize(objects, value_fn, field_fns_and_ratios):
    field_fns = [fr[0] for fr in field_fns_and_ratios]
    ratios = [fr[1] for fr in field_fns_and_ratios]
    grouping = grouped(objects, value_fn, field_fns)
    fit_fn = ratio_fit_fn(grouping, ratios)
    return minimize(fit_fn, [1 for _ in ratios])


objects = [
    {"U": True, "V": True, "value": 1},
    {"U": True, "V": False, "value": 2},
    {"U": False, "V": True, "value": 3},
    {"U": False, "V": False, "value": 4},
    {"U": True, "V": False, "value": 5},
    {"U": False, "V": True, "value": 6},
    {"U": True, "V": True, "value": 7},
    {"U": False, "V": False, "value": 8},
    {"U": True, "V": True, "value": 9},
    {"U": False, "V": True, "value": 10},
]

print(optimize(objects, field_fn("value"), [(field_fn("U"), 0.2), (field_fn("V"), 0.85)]))
```

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer! It might take me a while to test due to not knowing python / life stuff but I'll definitely get back when I have. I'm assuming that the messy algebra way would be faster, if I completed it?

Comment: @gubitza The messy algebra way should be faster for the case of 2 indicator variables. If you're coding in a language without closures and higher order functions, you'll need a lot more work for the calculus version.