# Algorithm to change polygon sides & angles

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, polygon, cad

I'd like some help on what I think is a non-trivial algorithm. Essentially this can be thought of as a 2D cad problem but I am unable to find any algorithms online:

I have a user-defined, non-self-intersecting polygon of n straight sides. The user has the option to define angles and side lengths, and the ability to lock those so they cannot be changed.
[image: User-defined Polygon]

If the user wants to change, for example, the length of [p1-p2], how can I search the polygon for changeable sides and angles that can yield the target length without altering any of the constrained variables?

Approaches I have considered:

- Loop round the sides of the shape (alternating clockwise and anti-clockwise) and form either a tri or quad with the changing side and the current iteration side. Search for editable dimensions, perturb them and see if they result in a length closer to the target, then if so keep changing it until the target is reached. Once reached, translate other points accordingly.
- A "hub and spoke" model where each side creates a triangle with the centroid, and the search is carried out this way.

I always get stuck at translating the other sides without editing their constraints and it seems to just bounce back from one side to another.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For each requested modification there may exist infinite polygons that satisfy all current constraints and the one added as new expected value. This makes it an optimization problem, but I don't see any optimization goal (fitness or cost) in your definition. For example, when we are asked to change the length of p2-p3, we can move p2, p3 or both, and even worth, nothing prevents us from altering the p0 angle. Is that what you want? If not, you need to add some cost function to your problem first.

Comment: @saastn Thanks for your comment. That is correct, I want it to be able to change any unlocked side or angle to obtain the desired length. That way, the user can keep locking and constraining the optimiser if it is changing things the user doesn't like.

I realise it is a massive optimisation task, however I know it can be done because 2D cad programs often have this functionality, eg SolidWorks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether there is a better approach, but gradient descent seems pretty flexible to me here.

You have some set of points, representing twice as many coordinates.

You have some set of equations that you also wish solved.  Very nonlinear equations, but fewer than the number of coordinates.  Equations like

```
K1 = length(P1-P2)

K2 = cos(angle P0-P5-P4)
   = dot(P0 - P4, P4 - P5) / length(P0-P4) * length(P5-P4)
```

Each equation may be rewritten as 0 is how far away it is from being solved.  Then square it.  Then add them together.

```
0 = (length(P1-P2) - K1)**2 +
    (dot(P0 - P4, P4 - P5) / length(P0-P4) * length(P5-P4) - K2)**2
```

And now like I did in a toy example in [How to adjust groups of numbers to match ratios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75621538/how-to-adjust-groups-of-numbers-to-match-ratios/75623853#75623853) you can start with your solution and do gradient descent.  You don't even have to analytically solve anything - just a straight numerical solution works!

This won't give very satisfactory answers yet.  But you can add extra equations such as "the sum of all of the locked lengths is ___" and "the average of all of the positions is ___".

And now what will happen is that the very first step will push `P1` and `P2` apart.  Thus making breaking the locked equations that you have.  And then the system will start trying to adjust everything simultaneously to get back to satisfying all of the equations at once.  Before long it should find one of the infinite solutions out there.

Tip.  You can add terms that give non-zero values if, say, the length of `P4-P5` is below 1 or above 100.  That will make sure that no segment winds up disappearing.

Tip 2.  I did not worry about "non self-intersecting".  But you can define a complicated function like "square of the length of self-intersecting regions".  Throw that in to the objective to minimize, and if it gets tangled it will immediately try to untangle itself.