# Finding the minima of a multivariable function through code

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

I have a multivariable function (9 variables), and I want to find where the function records a minimum value. The function is as follows:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygj4p.png]

It also has a few constraints:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FgPv.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIH4K.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/enyj4.png]

I tried a brute force algorithm, but because of 9 variables, it has a really high time complexity, and will take a long time to run. Is there a much better way to do this?

Comment: I suggest you use the four equations you've provided as constraints to turn your problem into a 5 variable problem, then do some gradient descent. Do you need a global minimum or is a local minimum okay?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your approach. Global minimum is what's needed.

Comment: Constrained optimization is the bailiwick of Operations Research, you should consider migrating this to https://or.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Do you need an explanation of how to do gradient descent on a surface implicitly defined by a set of equations? Or is just knowing you have to enough to point you in the right direction?

Comment: I went through some literature and found that I have to find the partial derivatives of the overall function, and then use the cost function to get closer to the root. It would be great if you could tell me more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to steal code from [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75621538/how-to-adjust-groups-of-numbers-to-match-ratios/75623853#75623853) of mine.

First, a trick from [The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/) for computing numerical derivatives of functions of one variable.

```
def derivative (fn, delta=0.001):
    def inner (x):
        return (fn(x + delta/2) - fn(x - delta/2)) / delta
    return inner
```

Here I'm using closures to make the concept straightforward.  Pass in a function, get an approximate derivative function.  If your language doesn't have closures you can do the same calculations, but may have to write some repetitive code for each function.  Either way, we can compute a good approximation to a derivative without having to analytically work anything out.

Now we have a function `f(v)` where `v` is a vector.  We'd like to compute an approximate gradient at a point.  Well...

```
def gradient (fn, point):
    grad = []

    for i in range(len(point)):
        # This will be the function of just varying this dimension.
        def fn_i (x):
            point2 = [_ for _ in point]
            point2[i] += x
            return fn(point2)
        grad.append(derivative(fn_i)(0))

    return grad
```

(You might want to turn this raw array into some sort of vector object.  But that is a programming detail.)

And here is basic gradient descent.

```
def minimize (fn, start_point, step_size=1, finish_size = 0.0000001, max_iter=1000000):
    point = start_point
    n = 0
    while finish_size < step_size and n < max_iter:
        n += 1
        g = gradient(fn, point)
        g2 = sum((x*x for x in g))**0.5
        if 0 == g2:
            return point
        else:
            # The direction in which we go.
            # A vector of length 1 pointing AWAY from the gradient.
            vec = [-x/g2 for x in g]
            start = fn(point)
            point2 = [step_size * vec[i] + point[i] for i in range(len(point))]
            end = fn(point2)
            while start < end:
                step_size /= 2
                point2 = [step_size * vec[i] + point[i] for i in range(len(point))]
                end = fn(point2)
            point = point2
    return point
```

Note that I have logic to avoid infinite loops, but it is possible to get stuck bouncing back and forth between points.  If that is a concern, you can make sense to make the step each time be of length `step_size * (0.9 + 0.2*random.random())`.  Now it can't get stuck.

Now how does this help?  Well you're trying to minimize `f(v)` subject to a set of `k` constraints that can be written as:

```
constraint[0](v) = 0
constraint[1](v) = 0
.
.
.
constraint[k-1](v) = 0
```

where `constraint` is an array of functions which is the difference of the two terms that are supposed to be equal.

Our first question is how to solve for the constraints.  To do that we minimize:

```
sum([con[v]*con[v] for con in constraints])
```

When that is 0, all of our constraints are satisfied.  And the minimization code above does a pretty good job of solving it.

OK, we now need to know how to satisfy our constraints, but how do we do gradient descent on the surface that they define?  Here is our strategy.

```
Calculate the gradient of the function.
Project it onto the tangent plane of the surface.
while true:
    Try a step backwards along the tangent gradient (gradient = increasing, go the other way)
    Find the surface again
    if the value decreased:
        actually make the step
        break out of the loop
    else:
        cut step size in half
```

Which of these steps do we know how to do?

Well first, we know how to take a gradient - there is code for that above.

Now we know how to find `gradient(constraint[i], v)` for `i in range(k)`.  We can use that to populate an array of vectors that are all at right angles to our surface.  We'd like to turn that array into an [orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) that spans the space at right angles to our surface.  The idea here is like this untested code (which you'll need to do some work to make actually work).

```
for i in range(len(vectors)):
   if epsilon < length(vectors[i]):
       vectors[i] = vectors[i] / length(vectors[i])
       for j in range(i+1, k):
           vectors[k] = vectors[k] - dot(vectors[i], vectors[k]) * vectors[i]
vectors = [v in vectors if epsilon < length(v)]
```

now why did we want to do that?  Very simply because to project the gradient to the tangent space we can simply remove the part at right angles to the surface like this:

```
grad_f = gradient(f, v)
for constraint in vectors:
    grad_f = grad_f - dot(constraint, grad_f) * constraint
```

And now that we have a gradient tangent to the surface, we can take a step along that direction in the opposite direction from the gradient.  Because the surface bent and our step didn't, we're no longer on the surface, but we just find the surface again, and we've wound up taking a step along the surface towards a minimum.

In general you just select a bunch of points to start from, and try to minimize.  This doesn't guarantee the absolute minimum.  But in practice, in high dimensional space it is surprisingly hard to get stuck.  So you probably do find a really good minimum.  (Machine learning works in part because of this fact.)

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. But, I had a doubt for the gradient function - what's fn and point (the parameters being passed)

Comment: Also, any idea how I'll be able to define my constraints vector as per my constraint equaions?

Comment: Each constraint is some function = 0. The sum of squares of the constraints is minimized to 0 on your surface. You use that to find the surface. And you also use constraints to find the component of the gradient normal to the surface - take that away and you get the component tangent to the surface.

Comment: How rare to see Lisp used here.  Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled your problem with the [Excel solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040).
Before using the solver, it has to be activated as Excel add-on.

### Input table and results

(German decimal separator is comma, sorry for that!):

[image]

The solver was tasked to minimize an objective. The objective is the sum of the value `T` plus the sum of squared errors. The six errors are the differences between required value and actual value for each of the constraint expressions.

The sum of squared errors is multiplied by 10000 as penalty factor to enforce small errors.

To abbreviate typing, I introduced names like `_c1=cos(theta1)` and `_s6=sin(theta6)` using the [Excel name manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4).

Note that the constraint expressions can be simplified quite a lot due to reoccurring subexpressions.

I am not sure if I typed in everything correctly, but the solving only takes a couple of seconds.

---

### Second attempt with C#

Then I used the [mathnet-numerics](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics) library to solve the minimization with the [Nelder-Mead](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization/NelderMeadSimplex.htm) method. This is a derivative-free algorithm for multivariate optimization.

**My C# code:**

```
//  installed NuGet Package Math.NET Numerics
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.Optimization;

namespace akNelderMeadDemo
{
    public class SOFunction : IObjectiveFunction
    {
        const double Pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
        const double Grd60 = Pi2 / 6;
        const double Grd45 = Pi2 / 8;

        private int evalCount = 0;

        public SOFunction()
        {
            //  we have nine parameters
            //  this is also returned in InitialGuess(), see below
            Point = CreateVector.Dense<double>(9);

            //  initial values taken from Excel
            Point[0] = 0;
            Point[1] = 0.541824973;
            Point[2] = 1.148728295;
            Point[3] = 0.125762746;
            Point[4] = 1.712425399;
            Point[5] = 0.262748905;
            Point[6] = 0.170976846;
            Point[7] = 0.170178244;
            Point[8] = 0.073184024;
        }

        public Vector<double> Point { get; set; }

        public double Value { get; set;}

        public bool IsGradientSupported => false;

        public Vector<double> Gradient => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool IsHessianSupported => false;

        public Matrix<double> Hessian => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public IObjectiveFunction CreateNew() => new SOFunction();

        private static double Cos(double x) => Math.Cos(x); 
        private static double Sin(double x) => Math.Sin(x); 

        private static void O(string s = "") => Console.WriteLine(s);

        public void EvaluateAt(Vector<double> point)
        {
            const int Penalty = 100000;

            point.CopyTo(Point);

            var t1 = Point[0];
            var t2 = Point[1];
            var t3 = Point[2];
            var t4 = Point[3];
            var t5 = Point[4];
            var t6 = Point[5];
            var l1 = Point[6];
            var l2 = Point[7];
            var l3 = Point[8];

            var c1 = Cos(t1);
            var s1 = Sin(t1);
            var c2 = Cos(t2);
            var s2 = Sin(t2);
            var c3 = Cos(t3);
            var s3 = Sin(t3);
            var c4 = Cos(t4);
            var s4 = Sin(t4);
            var c5 = Cos(t5);
            var s5 = Sin(t5);
            var c6 = Cos(t6);
            var s6 = Sin(t6);

            var T1 = 2 * l1 * (l1 * c1) + 2 * l2 * (l1 * c1 + l2 * c2 / 2) + l3 * (l1 * c1 + l2 * c2 + l3 * Cos(-Grd60) / 2);
            var T2 = 2 * l1 * (l1 * c3) + 2 * l2 * (l1 * c3 + l2 * c4 / 2) + l3 * (l1 * c3 + l2 * c4 + l3 * Cos(0) / 2);
            var T3 = 2 * l1 * (l1 * c5) + 2 * l2 * (l1 * c5 + l2 * c6 / 2) + l3 * (l1 * c5 + l2 * c6 + l3 * Cos(Grd45) / 2);
            var T = Math.Sqrt(T1 * T1 + T2 * T2 + T3 * T3);

            var e1 = (l1 * c1) + (l1 * c1 + l2 * c2 / 2) + (l1 * c1 + l2 * c2 + l3 * Cos(-Grd60) / 2) - 0.75;
            var e2 = (l1 * s1) + (l1 * s1 + l2 * s2 / 2) + (l1 * s1 + l2 * s2 + l3 * Sin(-Grd60) / 2) - 0.1;
            var e3 = (l1 * c3) + (l1 * c3 + l2 * c4 / 2) + (l1 * c3 + l2 * c4 + l3 * Cos(0) / 2) - 0.5;
            var e4 = (l1 * s3) + (l1 * s3 + l2 * s4 / 2) + (l1 * s3 + l2 * s4 + l3 * Sin(0) / 2) - 0.5;
            var e5 = (l1 * c5) + (l1 * c5 + l2 * c6 / 2) + (l1 * c5 + l2 * c6 + l3 * Cos(Grd45) / 2) - 0.2;
            var e6 = (l1 * s5) + (l1 * s5 + l2 * s6 / 2) + (l1 * s5 + l2 * s6 + l3 * Sin(Grd45) / 2) - 0.6;

            var errorSum = e1 * e1 + e2 * e2 + e3 * e3 + e4 * e4 + e5 * e5 + e6 * e6;

            Value = T + errorSum * Penalty;
        }

        public IObjectiveFunction Fork() => new SOFunction() { Point = Point, Value = Value };

        public Vector<double> InitialGuess() => Point;

        internal void ShowResult(MinimizationResult result)
        {
            var p = result.MinimizingPoint;
            O($"theta1 = {p[0]}");
            O($"theta2 = {p[1]}");
            O($"theta3 = {p[2]}");
            O($"theta4 = {p[3]}");
            O($"theta5 = {p[4]}");
            O($"theta6 = {p[5]}");
            O($"l1 = {p[6]}");
            O($"l2 = {p[7]}");
            O($"l3 = {p[8]}");
            O($"Value = {result.FunctionInfoAtMinimum.Value}");
            O($"Iterations = {result.Iterations}");
        }
    }

    internal class Minimizer
    {
        internal static void Minimize()
        {
            var nms = new NelderMeadSimplex(convergenceTolerance: 1e-15,
                                            maximumIterations: 1000000);
            var objectiveFunction = new SOFunction();

            Console.WriteLine("Minimizing ...");

            var initialGuess = objectiveFunction.InitialGuess();
            var result = nms.FindMinimum(objectiveFunction, initialGuess);

            if (result.ReasonForExit == ExitCondition.Converged)
            {
                objectiveFunction.ShowResult(result);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{result}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method actually comes up with a solution after fractions of a second. But unfortunately, it does not look identical to what I've found before. The Excel version implicitely assumes all variables to be positive. That might be the difference. Rounding and accuracy thresholds might also be causing this.