# How to select a multiset from a list due to the probability amount of its value?

Tags: algorithm, permutation, multiset

I have a list of multisets, generated from a list of candidate value, which should match a fixed amount (summing each others).

For example, given those values:

```
elem = [4, 16]
```

And a target amount:

```
tN = 64
```

Heres are the possible outcome:

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 16
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 16 16
4 4 4 4 16 16 16
16 16 16 16
```

Now, I set some probabily on each value:

```
prob = [0.2, 0.9] // prob of 4 and 16
```

I need to select randomly a multiset which "tends" to contain more the values due to their prob amount.

In the example above, `16 16 16 16` should have "more" probability to be taken rather than `4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 16` (since 16 has 0.9 prob, which is higher than 0.2, and that multiset is more "16" oriented).

As well `4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 16 16` rather than `4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 16`, and so on (so rarely it should take `4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4`).

Which is the right algo to random pick it due to its value's prob?

It should of course works with any kind of `elem` and `tN` (so for example `elem = [1, 4, 8, 16]` and `prob = [0.15, 0.56, 0.9, 0.7]`.

The only idea is: for each multiset, group and count each item, than multiply for its prop, ceil the value, and add to a list that multiset (for each value).

So:

```
16 16 16 16: 4 (4 time 16) * 0.9 and 0 (0 time 4) * 0.2
4 4 4 4 16 16 16: 3 (3 time 16) * 0.9 and 4 (4 time 4) * 0.2
```

But it seems to be not very "proportional" in case of lots item repetitions...

Answer (score 3):

So to be clear, the problem is that we are given a list of elements `elem`, a target `tN`, and want to pick a multiset out of the elements such that a random value `elem[i]` shows up in the output at proportion `prob[i]` of the time.

The random procedure will look like randomly picking elements from `elem` where the `i`th element has probability `q[i]` of being chosen.  If we wind up exceeding the target, we'll throw our attempt away and try again.  We'd like to pick `q` such that the proportions in the final answer come out to `prob`.

Given `q`, we can figure out the proportions in the final answer with dynamic programming.  If `q` is `[0.2, 0.8]` and `elem = [2, 5]`, the table you'd need to fill in starts like this:

```
table = [
    {'i': 0, 'p': 1, 'expected': [0.0, 0.0]},
    {'i': 1, 'p': 0, 'expected': [0.0, 0.0]},
    {'i': 2, 'p': 0.2, 'expected': [0.2, 0.0]},
    {'i': 3, 'p': 0, 'expected': [0.0, 0.0]},
    {'i': 4, 'p': 0.04, 'expected': [0.08, 0.0]},
    {'i': 5, 'p': 0.8, 'expected': [0.0, 0.8]},
    {'i': 6, 'p': 0.008, 'expected': [0.024, 0.0]},
    {'i': 7, 'p': 0.32, 'expected': [0.32, 0.32]},
    ...
]
```

where each row is the probability `p` of having arrived at `i` during an attempt, and `expected` gives the expected number of times we expect to use that element in arriving at that point.  So, for example, one of the rows is:

```
    {'i': 4, 'p': 0.04, 'expected': [0.08, 0.0]},
```

Which means:

- We might at some point have a sum of `4`.
- The probability we did was `0.04`.
- The expected number of `2`'s used in arriving at `4` is `0.08`.  (Probability `0.04` of using 2 `2`s, comes out to `0.08`.)
- The expected number of `5`'s used in arriving at `4` is `0.0`.  (Probability `0.04` of using 0 `5`s, comes out to `0.0`.)

The rule is that for the `k`th element, you can try each value of `elem`, and say, "If I arrived at `k`, I must have previously been at `k-elem[i]`."

The contribution to `table[k]['p']` is now `table[k-elem[i]]['p']*q[i]`.  (Probability of arriving at `k-elem[i]` times probability of choosing `elem[i]` next.)

For `j` not equal to `i` the contribution to `table[k]['expected'][j]` is `table[k-elem[i]]['expected'][j] * q[i]`.

The contribution to `table[k]['expected'][i]` is `(1 + table[k-elem[i]]['expected'][i]) * q[i]`.

This is sufficient to fill in the table.

---

OK, now how do we find `q`?

Well, we want the following to be true:

```
sum of q = 1.0
for each i:
    prob[i] = table[tN]['expected'][i] / (sum of table[tN]['expected'])
```

Let's let `f(q)` be the sum of squares of the errors in these equations.  We can minimize `f` (subject to the elements of `q` being between `0` and `1`).  If we get `f` close to 0, then we've got a pretty good answer to your original problem.

We can minimize `f` with gradient descent.  If you're not familiar with it, I described it pretty well in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951178/finding-the-minima-of-a-multivariable-function-through-code/75952469#75952469).

This will not always work.  For example in the list I used, every way to arrive at `tN = 9` needs 2 `2`s and a `5`.  You can't get any other ratio.

But if it IS possible to get the desired ratios, we should figure out how to.

Comment: So not starting from multiset, instead generate them dynamically? Or I am not sure I got your point. I'm on c++, can you show me a complete pseudo code example?

Comment: @markzzz Yes, that is the idea. Generate a random vector with the right average frequencies, then count elements, then get your multiset. Generating a complete pseudo code example is beyond my current generosity on this.

Comment: Note, if you're trying to generate a multiset from `[1, 2]` adding up to 100 with even numbers of 1s and 2s, this will produce multisets with 33 2's much more often than 10 2's. I know how to create more varied multisets with a similar strategy, but it takes more work.